# can you tell me the usage of shall in daily speaking

Tags: grammar

I'm writting to ask for some help 
Can you tell me the usages of shall in daily speaking 
Thank you.

Comment: In US daily speech, 'shall' is never used. It is only used in older texts (like the Ten Commandments). If you use it, it will stand out as weird or British sounding (which is not to say that British people use it more often or are weird, just that that is the perception)

Answer (score 2):

OALD online has a good survey. They have three uses. No.1 the shall-futur is becoming old-fasioned. No.3 is old-fashioned or formal. So only no.2 is actually used: shall in questions with I and we.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shall?q=shall

Comment: ... and also in legal and legal-like documents, where it means "must".